# How to use WhatsApp Web in WKWebview with Swift?

Tags: swift, webkit, wkwebview, whatsapp

I want to open WhatsApp Web in WKWebview to use it as a second phone number.

I used a "userAgent" because the URL https://web.whatsapp.com wasn't working properly. The site is now open for WhatsApp Web, but;

I get a code by typing my phone number, open my WhatsApp application to confirm this code and enter the code to connect the device.

WhatsApp is stuck on the "Signing In" screen and the WebView in my app cannot log in.

My code is as follows.

```
    var whatsappWebView: WKWebView!

override func loadView() {
    whatsappWebView = WKWebView()
    whatsappWebView.navigationDelegate = self
    view = whatsappWebView
}

    private func getWhatsappWebView() {
    
    let url = URL(string: "https://web.whatsapp.com")!
    let userAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_14_6) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/12.1.2 Safari/605.1.15"
    whatsappWebView.customUserAgent = userAgent
    whatsappWebView.configuration.defaultWebpagePreferences.preferredContentMode = .mobile
    whatsappWebView.scrollView.alwaysBounceVertical = false
    whatsappWebView.scrollView.alwaysBounceHorizontal = false
    whatsappWebView.scrollView.bounces = false
    whatsappWebView.allowsBackForwardNavigationGestures = true
    whatsappWebView.load(URLRequest(url: url))
}
```